# Quiero mostrar datos de una base de datos en un input con livewire

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, livewire

estoy intentando mostrar datos de una base de datos en una vista usando livewire. Ya obtengo el id pero deseo mostrar mas datos apartir de ese id.

Código de la vista:

```
 <!--Codigo Prod.-->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>Cod. Prod.</label>
                        <div wire:ignore>
                            <select class="select2" wire:model="producto">
                                <option value="" selected>Seleccion Codigo</option>
                                @foreach ( $productos as $product )
                                <option  value="{{$producto->id}}">{{$producto->codigo_producto}}</option>
                                @endforeach 
                            </select>
                            

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Aqui deseo obtener el nombre del Producto-->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label>Producto</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="producto" disabled>
                    </div>
```

el render:

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.salidas',[
            'unidades'=>Unidad::get(),
            'productos'=>Producto::get(),            
            'cuentas'=>Cuenta::get(),
            'grupos'=>Grupo::get()

        ]);

    }
```

Porfavor si alguien pudiera ayudarme en algo q parece sencillo pero soy muy nuevo con esto :3

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer que cuando seleccione un `id` se reinicie la view y envías ese id a tu función en el controlador, obtienes el valor de `Request`, ahí haces una consulta con ese id, tipo así:

```
Producto::where('id', $id)->first()
```

Igual checa la docu: [documentación de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests)